# searching the html source code of a url using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

i am new to curl (php). by new i mean i just started 20 minutes ago. the aim is to grab the html source code of a url provided, search for a given word and extract the next 5 lines of code.

so far all i know is how to get the source code. not search for a string and get next 5 lines. so far what i have is this

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content=curl_exec($ch);

$htmlcontent = htmlspecialchars($content);

echo $htmlcontent;

curl_close($ch);
```

for example, take google.com. i want to get its source code, search for the exact word 'status:' and extract/echo the next five lines after its first occurence.

Comment: "i just started 20 minutes ago". My, you give up early.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing :) @CodeCaster

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: no dude....thats exactly what im using right now, the problem is all this stiff is not under curl and curl libraries.....i am supposed to not use use strpos and file functions

Comment: @Nibhrit: That's a rather arbitrary restriction. You can't do it with cURL alone. Are you looking for HTML parsing functions, e.g. the http://php.net/dom extension?

Comment: Why not use file_get_contents() for this?

Comment: Thank You all....it's been solved, i dont need to use cURL anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

php has multiple functions to search strings, for example [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos). You can use it to find the index of `status` in the downloaded string. You can it again to find newlines from that index on (`"\n"`).

When you have determined the start and last index of the string you want to extract, use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to actually extract it.

Comment: no dude....thats exactly what im using right now, the problem is all this stiff is not under curl and curl libraries.....i am supposed to not use use strpos and file functions

Comment: @Nibhrit What do you mean by `stiff`? Why are you "supposed to not use" `strpos`?

Comment: i have written the code to do what i need without curl...thats when my supervisor told me to scrap it and use curl functions instead....so "i am not supposed to be using strpos and stuff"....and so im clear, ive not been at it for just 20 minutes, try more like 3 hours

Comment: @Nibhrit Most likely, your supervisor referred to the downloading part, where you used `file_get_contents` before. Oh, and consider another place to work - you won't get anything done with such strict and completely arbitrary rules, not to speak of the extreme micro-management.

Comment: i just talked to the guy and turns out he doesnt know ehat he's talking about. so im free from curl for now.
:)
and thanks for the suggestion mate!